# pointers in parse class with swift code

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to insert a text under description column, and it keep giving me error, I think I'm having this issue because I wasn't able to use the pointer properly.. is there any one can help, I watched a number of tutorial video's as to how to setup the pointer in Parse, and that didn't solve the issue.

Thanks.

```
let me = self.textField.text
let query = PFQuery(className: "Store")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId ("product", block: {
(object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
if error != nil
{
print(error)
}
else if let transaction = object {
transaction["discription"] = "\(me)"
transaction.saveInBackground()
print(object!.objectForKey("discription"))
}
})
```

Comment: Is the `query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId` ever returning an object for the id you use?

Comment: yes, is that wrong :(

Comment: Well, using it with an id of `"product"` isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer, the best possible answer I got was, not store any information to the DB till all the input is done from the last page. It means you carry over the input as temp to each pages, then save it at the end... :)